# How to intercept a key input without typing it?

Tags: python, arduino

Recently I'm making an hardware hotkey macro for gaming out of Python & Arduino.
My intention was, When I press 'a' key, this program operates a hotkey like 'upArrow + z' or something.

But there is a fatal flaw : 'a' and 'upArrow + z' are entered at the same time.
I want to only detect if 'a' is pressed but don't want it to be typed.

Any help for this?

Python code :

```
while True:
    if(win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x41) & 0x8000): 
        py_serial.write('a'.encode()) 
    while(win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x41) not in [0, 1]):
        pass
```

Arduino code :

```
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        receivedChar = Serial.read();
        if (recievedChar == 'a') {
            keyboard.press(something);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import getch
char = getch.getch() # User input, but not displayed on the screen
char = getch.getche() # also displayed on the screen
```

Hint: On Windows, you can use:

```
import msvcrt
# ...
char = msvcrt.getch()
# or, to display it on the screen
char = msvcrt.getche()
```

taken from
https://pypi.org/project/getch/

Comment: I guess this have no use for this case...

Comment: getch() doesn't work when I don't give focus on terminal. I gotta use this program on games.